# Programador tareas windows 10 pregunta programa ejecutar script python

Tags: windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un script sencillo de python para enviar correos, hace unos dias funcionaba perfecto usando el programador de tareas de windows, ahora ya no ejecuta automaticamente el script  ya que sale una ventana que pregunta con que programa ejecutar  y si no indico de forma manual que es python no funciona, luego dejo ser automatico.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y en el explorador de archivos ya le pusiste a Python como programa predeterminado a ese script?

Comment: Realice el diligenciamiento de la ruta de python y la ruta del script pero tampoco me funciona, cuando lo ejecuto normalmente si realiza lo esperado, pero desde las tareas programadas hace unos días funcionaba perfectamente y ahora siempre pregunta con que programa ejecutar, ya he definido que los archivos .py sean ejecutados por defecto en python y tampoco, lo raro es que antes funcionaba y ahora dejo de hacerlo.

Comment: Y desde el CMD has probado ejecutarlo?? Porque no le preguntas en el [chat] a algún usuario experto en Python? Creo que @Candid Moe es experto en ello.

Answer (score -3):

El problema se encuentra en que intentas ejecutar el fichero .py como si fuera un programa. Puedes solucionarlo con varias opciones:

- Definir Python como predeterminado para ejecutar ficheros con la extensión .py
- Crear un script en batch/powershell para ejecutarlo y establecerlo como programa/script en la tarea
- En la casilla donde se indica programa o script indicar la ruta del binario de Pyhton y en argumentos añade la ruta del script .py

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.